# Как правильно сделать счетчик сообщений в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Как правильно сделать счетчик сообщений в discord.py чтобы одновременно с этим работали и команды.

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
global points
points = 0

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])

@bot.command() # Не передаём аргумент pass_context, так как он был нужен в старых версиях.
async def hello(ctx): # Создаём функцию и передаём аргумент ctx.
    author = ctx.message.author # Объявляем переменную author и записываем туда информацию об авторе.
    print(author)
    await ctx.send(f'Hello, {author.mention}!') # Выводим сообщение с упоминанием автора, обращаясь к переменной author.

@bot.command()
async def coin(ctx):
    random_number = random.randint(0, 1)
    if random_number == 0:
        link_avers = 'https://numizmat.com.ua/catalog/coins/img/5_kop-2015_a-big.jpg'
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x22ee22, title='Орёл')  # Создание Embed'a
        embed.set_image(url = link_avers)  # Устанавливаем картинку Embed'a    url=json_data['link']
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)  # Отправляем Embed
    elif random_number == 1:
        link_revers = 'https://numizmat.com.ua/catalog/coins/img/5_kop-2015_r-big.jpg'
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xee2222, title='Решка')  # Создание Embed'a
        embed.set_image(url=link_revers)  # Устанавливаем картинку Embed'a    url=json_data['link']
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)  # Отправляем Embed

@bot.command() #команда проверки
async def money(ctx):
    print(points)

@bot.event #счётчик сообщений
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith(''):
        global points
        points += 1
        print(points)
bot.run(settings['token']) # Обращаемся к словарю settings с ключом token, для получения токена
```

При включении в код счётчика команды перестают работать.

Answer (score 2):

> При включении в код счётчика команды перестают работать.

В `on_message()`, перед подсчетом, добавьте строку `await bot.process_commands(message)`. Таким образом, бот сначала будет проверять сообщение на команду, а уже затем, после выполнения команды - подсчитывать.

**Должно получиться как-то так:**

```
@bot.event #счётчик сообщений
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return 
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        global points
        points += 1
        print(points)
```